# Profiler for XCode, iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, profiler

Does anybody know of a 3rd party profiler for XCode with the iPhone?

I really don't like instruments, it's a pain to try to figure out whats going on. Allocations and leaks are fine, its just the CPU Sampler that I don't like.

I really liked Shark but they have stopped updating that and it doesn't work with iOS4.

Comment: Don't give up on Instruments, the CPU Sampler is great. Maybe have a look at the 2010 WWDC session videos, I remember they covered how to get most out of the CPU sampler. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Comment: I believe instruments and/or the debugger can grab stack samples. If you can get a look at those, you can find what needs to be optimized, by this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024

Comment: How do I run my app with time profiler? It is greyed out in the run with instruments section of xcode. I have tried opening a time profiler in instruments and attaching the app process but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that there are any, since (as far as I know) there is no published documentation from Apple as far as the protocol to use when communicating with the iPhone and attempting to profile a running application.